# Import "playwright.sync_api" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports

Tags: python, playwright, playwright-python

I am new to python and playwright and I am trying to import playwright.sync_api in my python project.
I am using VSCode and I have changed my interpreter to point at the python version I installed(3.11.2) and have performed the following...

```
pip install playwright
playwright install
```

I keep getting the error (Import "playwright.sync_api" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports) and cannot seem to find the correct answer to fix this issue.

I have tried uninstalling playwright and reinstalling as well as making sure that my playwright and python were up to date.

This is what I have for the import...

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
```

I get the error at playwright.sync_api

Comment: You might have installed multiple versions of python - or maybe 32 and 64 bit version at the same time. In that case you would install playwright to one but try running it with another. I recommend using virtual environment where you install packages to a separate space.

Comment: I ended up using a venv and got it working.

Answer (score 0):

try running playwright install
and if this dosent work then make sure you downloaded it in to the right dir

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed playwright in a folder of correct Python version that is also used by VS Code.

For example, you installed playwright in folder of Python of 3.12 version, so playwright files would be there `AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\`.
Then at the bottom right of VS Code, check what Python version interpreter is used and change it to correct version.